# Function only prints value for four files from a directory of 5K files, Python

Tags: python, nested-loops, break, logical-operators, continue

I am running a code which takes each row of a csv and finds the exact match of the entity inside each files of a directory. The problem here is that the code terminates after printing out matching values for four files, whereas there are 5K files in the directory. I think the issue is with my break or continue statement. Can someone please help me with this. Code till now:

```
import csv
import os
import re


path = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\5KFILES\\'

with open('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\codes_file.csv', newline='', encoding ='utf-8') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    for filenames in os.listdir(path):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filenames), encoding = 'utf-8') as my:
            content = my.read().lower()
            #print(content)
            for row in reader:
                if len(row[1])>=4:

                #v = re.search(r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(row[1])), content, re.I)
                    v = re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(row[1]) + r'\b', content, re.IGNORECASE)
                    if v: 
                        print(filenames,v.group(0))
                        break
```

Comment: Do you still encounter this issue if you were to remove the break? :)

Comment: Also the built in `glob` library is very useful to access multiple files
https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reader` is created before your `for` loop, and it is an iterator. Every time you reach the `for` line, iteration will continue where it had stopped. Once you reach the end of `reader`, the next `for` loops will be empty loops.

You can see what happens in this short example:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
iterator = iter(l)

for i in range(0, 16, 2):
    print('i:', i, "- starting the 'for j ...' loop")
    for j in iterator:
        print('iterator:', j)
        if j == i:
            break

i: 0 - starting the 'for j ...' loop
iterator: 0
i: 2 - starting the 'for j ...' loop
iterator: 1
iterator: 2
i: 4 - starting the 'for j ...' loop
iterator: 3
iterator: 4
i: 6 starting the 'for j ...' loop
iterator: 5
i: 8 starting the 'for j ...' loop
i: 10 starting the 'for j ...' loop
i: 12 starting the 'for j ...' loop
i: 14 starting the 'for j ...' loop
```

Each time the `for` loop executes, it continues to iterate on `iterator` where it had stopped before. Once the iterator is exhausted, the `for j...` loops are empty.

You should restart it on each loop:

```
for row in csv.reader(myFile):
    ....
```

or make a list:

```
reader = list(csv.reader(myFile))

....

for row in reader:
    ....
```

Comment: You can reset the file position and the reader will start at the beginning - `myFile.seek(0)`  - you just have to find the right place to do it.